# Install Webobjects 4.5.1 on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnustep, webobjects

My client using webobjects 4.5(one of the last versions that supports Objective-C) on backend. And I need to develop using this framework.
Problem is that I'm using Ubuntu linux
I've tried to found how I can install framework on my OS, but found only WO 5.4
What can you advise? How I can install WO 4.5 On ubuntu?

P.S. Found GnuStep project. Is it fully compatible alternative to WO 4.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Objective C runtime has never been ported to Ubuntu, and there is no reason for Apple to ever do this, one cannot run WO 4.5 on a Linux distro. I think it actually was shipped to also run on Windows NT and on HP/UX and Solaris, but these probably will not help you either.

I am not sure if you can use the GnuStep code for any commercial work. I would be surprised if any lawyer would ever sign off on its use. But YMMV.

Sorry, but there does not seem to be any good news for you.

Comment: GNUstep is used for commercial work. A few examples are Testplant, Brainstorm, IntarS. See http://www.gnustep.org/developers/whoiswho.html and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/142043/6194 Disclosure: I'm associated with the GNUstep project.

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with any of these frameworks; but it appears there are at least two that are meant to be WebObjects 4.5-compatible (with extensions of their own): [GNUstepWeb](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/GNUstepWeb) and [SOPE](https://github.com/inverse-inc/sope).

GNUstepWeb is part of GNUstep, but GNUstep on the whole is more analogous to Cocoa, not just WebObjects. I am skeptical that there is anything "fully compatible", but these two might be worth checking out.